# How to guarantee that input data for method in class is right?

Tags: php

I have two classes that sends messages on mail or SMS.
There is front entry point:

```
$obj  = new Mail();
$obj2 = new SMS();

$obj->init($data = array());
```

How to guarantee that input data $data has a correct format and all fields?

```
$data = array(
'email' => 'v@gmail.com',
'id'    => 2,
'name'  => 'Vasile'
);
```

What universal validation I can use in this case?

Comment: That's the whole point of OOP: you create a class that represents a specific data-type (ie an email address which you set using `$obj->setEmail($string);`, that setter then validates the input (`filter_var($string, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL);`, and if that validation fail, it throws an `InvalidArgumentExcpetion`. Where you need that data, you just add type-hints: `$obj->init` could look something like `public function init(UserData $data){}`, because it's an object, you can be certain the data it contains is validated correctly

Comment: You may do this comment as answer and explain more, beause very difficult for reading

Comment: @Halayem has provided a good standard solution.  If you have a modern PSR-0 compatible app setup with composer & composer.json you can use symfony's optionsResolver component and get a fully blown out solution that is easy to use and well thought out.  See  http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/options_resolver.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will do it like this:

```
class InputValidator {
    private static $_required_fields = array ("email"    => "emailRegex",
                                              "id"      => "idRegex",
                                              "name"    => "nameRegex");
    /**
      * @param array $data
      * @throws Exception
      *
      */
    public static function isMailValid($data) {
        if(!is_array($data) || count($data) == 0) {
            throw new InvalidArgumentException("data is empty");
        }

        foreach (self::$_required_fields as $requiredField => $regex) {
            if(!array_key_exists($requiredField, $data)) {
                throw new InvalidArgumentException (sprintf("missed: %s from input", $requiredField));
            }
            if(preg_match($regex, $data[$requiredField]) !== 1) {
                throw new InvalidArgumentException (sprintf("wrong field data: %s from input", $data[$requiredField]));
            }
        }
    }
    // same logic for isSmsValid ....
}
```

In your class Mail, i will add the check

```
class Mail {
    public function init($data) {
        try {
            InputValidator::isMailValid($data);
        }catch($e) {
            // log, print stackTrace ...
        }
    }
}
```

**Note:**
 - I haven't tested my code :( 
 - You  should provide the adequats RegEx

Comment: Don't validate email addresses using regex, use `filter_var`, it has a `FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL` filter constant. Also: use type-hints: `is_array($data)` can be left out if you use `public function foo(array $data)` <== the method will only be invoked if `$data` is an array

Answer (score 0):

You can do a fast and easy function or method for this, for example...

```
<?php

$data = array(
'email' => 'v@gmail.com',
'id'    => 2,
'name'  => 'Vasile'
);

function validateStruct($array)
{

    $error = 0;

    if (!filter_var($array["email"], FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
        $error++;
    }

    if(empty($array["id"])){

        if(!is_int($array["id"])){
            $error++;     
        }

        $error++;
    }

    if(empty($array["name"])){
        //$name = filter_var($array["name"], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING); //if you want return valid string
        $error++;
    }

    if(empty($error)){
        return true;
    }else{
        return false;
    }
}


if(validateStruct($data) == true){
    //send sms or do something
}

?>
```

Comment: If you don't use `isset()` you will get a lot of `undefined index` warnings.

Comment: In this case I think that the values can be empty but not the keys, for this sample i think that were returned for a sql query, but you can are right